# How to download a HuggingFace model 'transformers.trainer.Trainer'?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

In 1 code., I have uploaded hugging face 'transformers.trainer.Trainer' based model using save_pretrained() function
In 2nd code, I want to download this uploaded model and use it to make predictions. I need help in this step - How to download the uploaded model & then make a prediction?

Steps to create model:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, TrainingArguments, Trainer
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-large)
trainer = Trainer(
model,
args,
train_dataset=tokenized_train_ds,
eval_dataset=tokenized_val_ds,
data_collator=data_collator,
tokenizer=tokenizer,)

#Arguments used above not mentioned here - model, args, tokenized_train_ds, tokenized_val_ds, data_collator, tokenizer
#Below step train the pre-trained model
trainer.train()
```

I then uploaded this 'trainer' model using the below command:-

```
trainer.save_model('./trainer_sm')
```

In a different code, I now want to download this model & use it for making predictions, Can someone advise how to do this? I tried the below command to upload it:-

```
model_sm=AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("./trainer_sm")
```

And used it to make predictions by this line of code:-

```
model_sm.predict(test_features)
AttributeError: 'XLMRobertaForQuestionAnswering' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I also used 'use_auth_token=True' as an argument for from_pretrained, but that also didn't work.

Also, type(trainer) is 'transformers.trainer.Trainer' , while type(model_sm) is transformers.models.xlm_roberta.modeling_xlm_roberta.XLMRobertaForQuestionAnswering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have saved is the model which the trainer was going to tune and you should be aware that predicting, training, evaluation and etc, are the utilities of `transformers.trainer.Trainer` object, not `transformers.models.xlm_roberta.modeling_xlm_roberta.XLMRobertaForQuestionAnswering`. Based on what was mentioned the easiest way to keep things going is creating another instance of the trainer.

```
model_sm=AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("./trainer_sm")
reloaded_trainer = Trainer(
                    model = model_sm,
                    tokenizer = tokenizer,
                    # other arguments if you have changed the defaults 
                    )
reloaded_trainer.predict(test_dataset)
```